# 3ds max to ansys

Tags: 3d, 3dsmax, ansys

Is there a way to export 3ds max models to ansys for FEA works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3dsmax exports these, so if the format you need is not in the list, then you need a exporter, and I don't know it that exists.
But one tip is Polytrans - http://www.okino.com/conv/conv.htm

```
* 3D Studio (.3DS)
* Adobe Illustrator (*.AI)
* ASCII Scene Export (*.ASE)
* Lightscape - Material (*.ATR), Blocks (*.BLK), Parameter (*.DF), Layers (*.LAY), Preparation (*.LP), View (*.VW)
* Autodesk DWF (*.DWF)
* Autocad DWG (*.DWG)
* Autocad DXF (*.DXF)
* Autodesk FBX (*.FBX, *.DAE)
* Motion Analysis HTR File (*.HTR)
* IGES (*.IGS)
* JSR-184 (*.M3G)
* Wavefront Object (*.OBJ) and Material (*.MTL)
* StereoLitho (*.STL)
* Shockwave 3D (*.W3D)
* VRML97 (*.WRL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would probably be an iges file. It is exported from 3DS and imported by ANSYS. Keep in mind that iges files are not the cleanest geometry files and often need some cleanup after they are imported. Keep an eye out for any holes, or disconnected surfaces after you import it.